# Wordpress - Paginação em posts personalizados

Tags: php, wordpress, paginação

Olá, bom dia!

Bem, criei um post personalizado para um site Wordpress e gostaria de adicionar paginação ao loop, para tal estou tentando utilizar a função [paginate_links()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) e os parâmetros utilizados nos exemplos deste.

Inseri a paginação após o loop e a contagem de páginas ocorre corretamente, porém independente de qual página eu clique sempre mostra os mesmos posts.

Estou utilizando o Wordpress 5.4, em configurações de permalinks a opção "Nome do post" e testei se há algum problema com outros plugins.

Segue o código que estou tentando utilizar.

```
$id_user = get_current_user_id();

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_type'     => 'serviceorder',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key'      => 'cliente',
    'meta_value'    => $id_user
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a><br>
            <?php // $whoareyou = the_field('cliente'); ?>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
    ) );
    ?>

    </ul>
<?php else: ?>

    <p>Você não tem nenhuma OS registrada.<p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia dá uma olhada [aqui](https://br.wordpress.org/support/topic/loop-relacionados/) pois bem, acho que pode lhe ajudar com sua dúvida.